# `findmnt` and `ls` still see a physically disconnected external storage drive

Tags: systemd, mount, fstab, automount, exfat

Here is an `/etc/fstab` record example of one of the mounts as per `x-systemd.automount` and other goodies:

```
UUID=XXXX-XXXX /media/XXXX-XXXX auto noauto,nofail,nouser,uid=root,gid=users,umask=007,X-mount.mkdir,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=1,x-systemd.idle-timeout=60 0 2
```

Currently this external exFAT-formatted drive is physically disconnected from the PC, but I still get the following surprises

```
$ ls /media
ls: cannot access '/media/XXXX-XXXX': No such device
```

and

```
$ findmnt /media/XXXX-XXXX
TARGET           SOURCE    FSTYPE OPTIONS
/media/XXXX-XXXX systemd-1 autofs rw,relatime,fd=55,pgrp=1,timeout=60,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=24590
```

This obviously fools other software, which might potentially be using `findmnt` to determine whether the mount is up, to believe that the storage drive is actually mounted and to proceed with further actions.

How do I make sure that when the drive is physically disconnected, it is no longer considered by the Linux system?

Comment: seems to me tgat media is still mounted?

Comment: @djdomi, it's not, the record you see just reflects `fstab` and `systemd` relation.  There is no actual mount in either `mount`, `df`, `lsblk`, etc.

Comment: did you tried `eject` or `udisks --detach /dev/sdX` or `udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdb`in reference to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35508/eject-usb-drives-eject-command/129282)

Comment: @djdomi, the problem with this is that there is no device to begin with.  The device is gone and that's exactly what `ls` complains about for instance.  `lsblk` also does not provide any insight.  Of course I remember what was the name of the device and I tried to enter it manually in `eject` command, what naturally results in `eject: /dev/sdd: not found mountpoint or device with the given name` error message.

Comment: UUID=XXXX-XXXX /media/XXXX-XXXX is the X anomized?

Comment: @djdomi, yup, in reality letters are different, but that's irrelevant here.

Comment: why do you do this? is that a secret?